# Django + SQLite3 in Docker - Database automatically rolled back to initial state after new Docker build and start

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django project which uses SQLite3 database running in Docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire project directory
COPY . /app

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

# Expose port
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the development server
CMD ["python", "doc_manager/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/doc-manager-web
```

When I want to build/deploy new version in this set-up, I execute these 2 commands:

```
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

Both commands are successfully executed.

But, consider this use case:

1. I deploy the current version using the given set-up.
2. I perform some modifications in the database (CRUD operations). The database is now modified.
3. I then perform some changes in the code itself (not in the Dockerfile or in docker-compose.yml).
4. I re-run the `docker compose build` and `docker compose up` commands.

Then, **I end up with the initial state of the database without the modifications I performed in step number 2**.

How do I make sure that my SQLite3 database keeps it's modifications regardless of the code modifications I'll do in the future and regardless of how many times I re-build, stop and start again the whole Docker environment?

My SQLite3 database lives in the project's directory.

EDIT:
This is the folder structure of my Django project after putting the SQLite3 database file in the `data/` folder.

```
└───doc_manager  # Main Django project folder
    ├───core  # Django app
    │   ├───migrations
    │   │   └───__pycache__
    │   ├───templates
    │   │   └───core
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───data
    │   └───db.sqlite3  # The SQLite3 db file that is used in Django
    └───doc_manager
```

Comment: If the database file isn't in a directory in the `volumes:` list then it won't be persisted, in exactly the way you describe.  This can be surprisingly complicated to set up (permissions can be tricky too) and it's very common to use a server-based relational database in a second container.

Comment: "Database automatically rolled back to initial state after new Docker build and start"
That's exactly how docker works. It is completely ephemeral, and you need to specifically make something persistent (which will be saved at the host fs).

Answer (score 2):

The SQLite database file is stored within the project directory, which gets overwritten each time you rebuild the Docker container.
Here's an updated Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml configuration to achieve this:

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire project directory
COPY . /app

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

# Run the development server
CMD ["python", "doc_manager/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/app/doc_manager/data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Sounds interesting! Should I then create a new directory called db-data in my Django project and put my SQLite3 database in there? Or, am I missing something here? How will the Dockerfile know the SQLite3 is in the db-data directory?

Comment: db-data is the name of the volume in docker, when you build this docker it will map that volume with `/data` directory on your local. you don't need to do anything with it, it will be created automatically. just run with `docker compose up -d --build`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but this did not resolve the issue. It still rolls back the database to the initial state whenever I try to restart the docker container. Any ideas what's wrong?
I will accept the answer once it's working as expected.

Comment: I have now also added the current folder structure into the question after moving the database file into `data/` folder to have it in a separate volume in the Docker image.

Comment: @rogaloo check the new codes, hope it helps, it updated based on your project structure

Comment: you have to point db-data to where your sqlite mounted

Comment: Well, I have tried your suggested new code, but it still does not work. I am thinking if this could be related to me using `docker compose up` and `docker compose down` commands. Perhaps I should only use `docker compose up` once and the only `docker compose stop` and `docker compose start` after performing some changes to the code to restart it without losing all of the database data?

Comment: what do you think? I would need to get this solved as I'd like to use Docker with Django and having a consistent, not rolled back, SQLite3 database.

Comment: for anyone else looking at this. following @Omid Roshani's solution worked for me.